# Multi Language Support for a website

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using HTML/PHP/jQuery for a web site I have developed for a company. He has requested to add multi-language support for his web site.

I'm just trying to find out what would be the best way (or best practise method) to achieve this as I am sure there are many different ways you could do this.

I have found a site with a tutorial; [Click here](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html)

This uses PHP with sessions.

Would this be a good way to do this or would there be any better methods?

Just to add, the company's website has 30 pages and approximately 200-300 words per page.

Comment: You may want to consider the JQuery Plug-in at jquery.bunkerhill.com

Comment: Personally I prefer subdomains ?

Comment: Yep, key value pairs in separate files is the way to go.  You can use XML to define your language files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a url querystring parameter personally, I much prefer it cleaner as part of the URL, for example:

http://en.example.com/

or

http://www.example.com/en/

Then on top of this I tend to use the UNIX `gettext` style of doing translations which I think PHP supports - http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php.

It's a bit more of a pain when you get to the JavaScript side of things, but there's similar implementations for it.

Comment: Why would you not use a url querystring parameter to determine the language? The 'cleaner' way also implies that you need to copy all files for each language. So this much more work when you want to add another language or if you want to modify one page (because you have to modify each other file in all other language-subdirectorie, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this would be a way to declare your localization resources in your `php` application. Basically as this suggests you need a parity of objects that create `Key/Value` pairing between the resources you're localizing and the specific locale strings.

If you want to do this using pure `JavaScript` it's pretty much the same. You need declare objects in different `JavaScript` locale files like `locale-en.js`, `locale-de.js`, `locale-fr.js`, etc. This is done for specific locale strings delivered by your `JavaScript` and not your server-side of the code. What these files contain is along these lines:

**locale-en.js**

```
myApplication = myApplication || {};

myApplication.locale = {
    title: "English title",
    body: "English body",
    // Etc.
};
```

The rest of the files contain exactly the same objects but with strings in different languages. Then referencing those strings inside your client side code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="locale-*language*.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#title').text(myApplication.locale.title); //jQuery
    // Pure JavaScript
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = myApplication.locale.title;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts:

- Don't localize with JavaScript if you're concerned in the least about SEO/SEM
- If you're using a CMS of any sort, you'll need the content segmented in the database, with the corresponding localized field editable through the CMS
- If you're not using a CMS, consider loading in a specific PHP/HTML snippet file for the content of each page, in each language
- If you have a lot of localized strings, consider using `gettext()` and [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)